# Replacing fasta header without key-value pair file

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, fasta

I am trying the following to replace `fasta` headers without key-value pairs using `bioawk`

```
for infile in $(ls *.faa)
do
        prefix=$(basename $infile .faa)
        bioawk -c fastx '{ print ">"$prefix"_" ++i "\n"$seq }' < ${infile} > ${prefix}_hdrrn.faa
done
```

Basically, I want to change the headers in my `species_name.faa` file to

```
>species_name_1
>species_name_2
...
>species_name_n
```

The problem is the `$prefix` inside `bioawk` `print` is not working. The error I get is:

> bioawk: illegal field $(), name "prefix"  input record number 1, file
> source line number 1

Why the substitution is not happening?

Comment: There are a number of potential issues/pitfalls with your approach, but you can pass $prefix into bioawk as a variable using `-v`, e.g. `bioawk -v pref="$prefix" -c fastx '{ print ">"pref"_" ++i "\n"$seq }' < ${infile} > ${prefix}_hdrrn.faa`

Comment: copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was too easy with seqkit. using '`nr`' does the trick !

```
for infile in $(ls *.faa)
do
    prefix=$(basename $infile .faa)
    echo "prefix is ${prefix}"
    seqkit replace -p .+ -r ${prefix}_{nr} --nr-width 4 $infile -o ${prefix}_hdrrn.faa
done
echo "done"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `find`, which is safer than `ls` to iterate over files. Use a Perl one-liner to change sequence headers:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.faa' -exec \
  perl -i.bak -lpe 'if ( $. == 1 ) { chomp ( $species_name = `basename $ARGV ".faa"` ); } s{^>.*}{">${species_name}_" . ++$idx}e' {} \;
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

`$.` : Current input line number.
`$ARGV` : Current input file name.
`chomp` : Remove input line separator, here, newline.

`s{PATTERN}{REPLACEMENT}` : Replace regex PATTERN with REPLACEMENT.
`/e` : Evaluate `REPLACEMENT` as an expression in `s{PATTERN}{REPLACEMENT}`.
`^>` : Literal `>` at the beginning of the line.
`.*` : Any character repeated 0 or more times. Parens are for capturing this pattern.
`++$idx` : first, increment `$idx` by 1, then return its value. When first used, `$idx` is not defined and is treated as `0` in this expression. Thus, the first header has suffix `1`.

**See also:**

- [`find` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)
- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)
- [`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `$seq` is supposed to be the contents of the current input line, i.e. `$0` and if so then you should probably be using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

outdir='/some/where'
mkdir -p "$outdir" &&
for infile in *.faa
do
    prefix="${infile%.*}"
    bioawk -c fastx -v pfx="$prefix" '{ print ">" pfx "_" NR ORS $0 }' < "$infile" > "${outdir}/${prefix}_hdrrn.faa"
done
```

Note that I'm creating the output files in some other directory so their names don't clash with your input file names.

You don't actually need a shell loop though, you could just do it all in one call to awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

outdir='/some/where'
mkdir -p "$outdir" &&
bioawk -c fastx -v outdir="$outdir" '
    FILENAME != prev {
        close(out)
        outfile = FILENAME
        sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"_hdrnna&",outfile)
        out = outdir "/" outfile
        prev = FILENAME
    }
    { print ">" pfx "_" FNR ORS $0 > out }
' *.faa
```

The above is assuming that `bioawk`, which I've never used and don't have/want a copy of, essentially behaves the same way as every other `awk`.